# How to use ng-repeat in angularjs for display json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

How to display json data using ng-repeat in angularjs

here is my json-

```
$scope.data = [{
        "name": "PR",
        "roles": [{
            "name": "RPR1",
            "responsibilities": [{
                "processes": [{
                    "processName": "process 1"
                }, {
                    "processName": "process 2"
                }],
                "responsibilityName": "Resp1"
            }, {
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Resp2"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "RPR2",
            "responsibilities": [{
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Resp1"
            }, {
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Resp2"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Finance",
        "roles": [{
            "name": "RFinance1",
            "responsibilities": [{
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Fresp1"
            }, {
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Fresp2"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "RFinance2",
            "responsibilities": [{
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "RespF1"
            }, {
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "RespF2"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "IT",
        "roles": [{
            "name": "R1",
            "responsibilities": [{
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Resp1"
            }, {
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Resp2"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "RIT2",
            "responsibilities": [{
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Resp1"
            }, {
                "processes": null,
                "responsibilityName": "Resp2"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "",
        "roles": []

    }];
```

Here is my html code for display json data-

```
 <div class="container" ng-repeat="departments in data">

  <div class="row" ng-repeat="roles in departments.roles" >

    <div  class="col-sm-12 center"  >
        <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="responsibilities in roles.responsibilities"> 
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12 box  "></br>
                <div class="strike form-group" >
                    <span >{{responsibilities.responsibilityName}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-12 box" style="padding-right: 0px ! important;"></br>
                <div class="form-group content1 mCustomScrollbar" >
                    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="processes in responsibilities.processes" >
                        {{processes.processName}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

  </div><!-- /.row -->

</div>
```

I want to repeat div class="col-sm-3" for each responsibilities
Give me some suggestions....

Comment: What is your exact problem is loop not working ? Let me create a plunker for you

Comment: I don't see any problem. Just tested this code locally, and each `responsibility` is wrapped in a `col-sm-3`.

Comment: div class="col-sm-3" not repeat properly

Comment: What about it is not repeating properly?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/V5eWXZ?p=preview   see if it helps i can post as answer Let me know ...